# Would it be bad form to specifically ask someone to downvote a post of mine?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

So would it be bad form to ask someone to downvote one of my posts on worldbuilding (just temporarily) So I could get another hat?  Business in the front party in the back is for an up and down vote on the same day.  I don't really want to write a question or answer poorly just to get a down vote. :)

Comment: bahahahaha.  yes it is bad form but considering the hat you are trying to get I feel that it is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @James so would you do the honors!  ;)

Comment: Delighted to Sir.  That should do it

Comment: It is bad form and the creator of the hat knew full well it would encourage such bad form - so I wouldn't worry about it too much...

Comment: Even though @James downvoted me (and then upvoted it)  I don't have the hat yet.  Does the downvote need to wait until the hat shows up?  or is it just late in coming?

Comment: Everyone loves hats! Managed to get that one yesterday actually.

Comment: Maybe you need to make an edit???   Or it could just take time...

Comment: @James I waited, and waited.  I think the downvote needs to stay until the hat is awarded.

Comment: Ok let me know if it works.

Comment: @James It did! Thanks!

Comment: Please consider turning these comments into an answer.

Comment: @James Feel free to remove your negative vote anytime...  :)  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/519/wondering-what-would-happen-if-magic-was-constrained-by-conservation-of-energy ( I am of course assuming this was you, if not, oh well.

Comment: @bowlturner it wont let me change it unless you edit the post hahaha

Comment: @James, Well that is good to know!  I'll take a look at it and see if it can use some editing.

Comment: @James I did add some more, this actually prompted me to add a paragraph I've been meaning to add for quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that asking this is borderline.  In general it is bad form, but since the creator of the hat probably expected this this to happen, and it really won't have any long term negative effects on the site it can be over looked.